# Can Spring Session be turned off in Spring Boot 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-session, spring-boot-3

In my `Spring Boot 2.7.4` project, I use `Spring Session` with `Redis` by including these dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

This, along with a handful of application property settings to specify host, port, etc., this works fine.

Setting the following property allows Spring Session to be switched off. This is very convenient when running the service in an IDE in a development environment, for example, where you may not have access to a running Redis instance.

```
spring.session.store-type=NONE
```

However, I have just upgraded to `Spring Boot 3.0.4` and have found that this property is no longer supported. I would be very grateful if anyone can suggest an alternative way to switch off `Spring Session` for development work, while still leaving the dependencies and configuration in place ready for formal deployments.

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring Boot 3.x [Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-session-store-type)

You can define your own `SessionRepository` bean and cause the auto-configuration to back off.